# How to hide a tooltip in angularjs based application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of trs with nested tds. This is a angular based app. I am also using **tooltip.js** bootstrap plugin. What I'm trying to achieve is to hide a tooltip from tr when I mouseover on td. My HTML looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="model in somelist" name="someName" tooltip="someTooltip">  

  <td tooltip="someOtherTooltip" ng-mouseover="hideTooltip()"></td>

</tr>
```

and .js like this:

```
$scope.hideTooltip = function () {
    $("[name='someName']").tooltip('hide');
};
```

Comment: why ng-mouseover is inside td tooltip

Comment: Ideally you would put that in a directive and not a controller

Comment: It's not. My mistake. Editing right now.

Comment: Try this `$(".tooltip").hide();`

Comment: Thank you very much chiraq patel. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Performing DOM manipulations from Controller is a bad practice. You have to do it from directives. In your case, as suggested above, you'd better use ngHide like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="model in somelist" name="someName" tooltip="someTooltip">  
    <td tooltip="someOtherTooltip" ng-hide="tooltipIsHidden" ng-mouseover="hideTooltip()"></td>
</tr>
```

In your Controller:

```
$scope.hideTooltip = function () {
    $scope.tooltipIsHidden = true;
};
```

In real world, however, you'd need to pass an argument of the tooltip you want to hide, and use a property like tooltip.isHidden instead.

By the way, you might want to check out [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It ccntains Bootstrap UI components wrapped in Angular directives (including tooltip) with a lot of useful options.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide). I think its helpful to you cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to use UI Bootstrap.

Here is a link on how to use the tooltip functionality:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip